# Differentiable homeomorphism from a open set of $\mathbb{R^2}$ to an open set of $S^2$ that is not a parameterization

Tags: differential-geometry, spheres, parametrization

Show an example of a differentiable homeomorphism from a non-empty open set of $\mathbb{R^2}$ to an open set of $S^2$ that is not a parameterization.

I tried different functions but they were all  parameterization, can anyone help me thanks.

Comment: It suffices to find a differentiable homeomorphism between open subsets of the plane which is no diffeomorphism.

Comment: But if two surfaces are homeomorphic in $\mathbb{R^3}$ they are also diffeomorphic (and a open set of the plane can be seen as a surface in $\mathbb{R^3}$). i was thinking about a function that is a differentiable homeomorphism but the differential is not  injective, but i don't know how to find it

Comment: Do you know of an example of a strictly monotonic function of one variable which is differentiable but has zero derivative at some point? One usually learns this in an introductory calculus class.

Comment: $x^3$, why this question?

Comment: So what can you say about $(x,y)\mapsto (x^3,y^3)$?

Comment: Is differentiable but the  differential is not injective

Comment: and it’s a homeomorphism $\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$, so it fulfils all your requirements. If you really want something mapping into $S^2$, then compose with say a stereographic projection map (which is a diffeomorphism).